# Understanding $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of continuity

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, continuity, epsilon-delta

> $\textbf{Textbook defenition:}$ Let $A$ be a subset of $\mathbb{R}$. Let $f: A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and let $c \in  A$. We say that $f$ is continuous at $c$ if, given any number $\epsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that if $x$ is any point of $A$ satisfying $\mid x-c \mid<\delta$, then $|f(x)-f(c)|< \epsilon$.

---

In this definition, we have the freedom to choose $\epsilon$, that is, we sort of close in on $f(c)$ by the y-axis. Would the defenition still work if we have the freedom of choosing $\delta$? That is,

> Let $A$ be a subset of $\mathbb{R}$. Let $f: A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and let $c \in  A$. We say that $f$ is continuous at $c$ if, given any number $\delta>0$ there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that if $x$ is any point of $A$ satisfying $\mid x-c \mid<\delta$, then $|f(x)-f(c)|< \epsilon$.

---

In this case, we are closing in on $f(c)$ from the $\text{y-axis}$. Would this work? If it doesn't then why?

Comment: Every bounded function is continuous according to your definition.

Comment: @geetha290krm How is that so? Can you elaborate

Comment: Consider a unit step function.  $f(x) = 0$ if $x\le0$ and $f(x) = 1$ if $x>0.$  This function is not continuous.  Yet, for any $\delta> 0, |f(0+\delta) - f(x)| \le 1$  So, $\epsilon$ (slightly greater than $1$) exists, and does not force this function to be continuous.  In the traditional definition, $\epsilon$ can be arbitrarily small. Your revised definition does put that same constraint on $\epsilon.$

Answer (score 0):

> Let $A$ be a subset of $\mathbb{R}$. Let $f: A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and let $c \in  A$. We say that $f$ is continuous at $c$ if, given any number $\delta>0$ there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that if $x$ is any point of $A$ satisfying $\mid x-c \mid<\delta$, then $|f(x)-f(c)|< \epsilon$.

Let $f(x)=0, x<0$, $f(x)=1, x\ge 0$, according to your definition,

For any $\delta>0$, there exists $\epsilon=2$, such that whenever $|x-0|<\delta$, $|f(x)-f(0)|<2$

it is "continuous" at $x=0$, but obviously this is wrong, since $f$ is not continuous at $x=0$.

Answer (score 0):

**Human translation for the first definition**

$f$ is continuous at $c$ if and only if we can make $f(x)$ as close to $f(c)$ as we want, by choosing $x$ that is close enough to $c$.

If you want $f(x)$ to be extremely close to $f(c)$ then you need to choose $x$ that is also really close to $c$. From here the dependency is clear; you can choose an arbitrary $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ depends on $\epsilon$.

**Human translation for the second clause**

If we choose $x$ to be within certain distance from $c$, we guarantee that $f(x)$ will be within certain distance from $f(c)$.

Comment: And what's faulty about the second clause?

Comment: @Ellie_Wong the first definition guarantees that the difference $f(x)-f(c)$ can be extremely small, the second clause only guarantees that the difference will be finite, not necessarily small. Take for example $f(x)=1$ in $[-1,1]$ and $0$ everywhere else, this $f$ fits the second clause because $f(x)-f(c)<2$ for any $x$ and $c$ but it does not fit the first definition